# ASP CLassic JSON header issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp-classic

Any ideas why this is kicking up a fuss for my jquery ajax call.

```
Sub SetJsonHeader()
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
End Sub

something = Request.Form( "formLabel" )
SetJsonHeader()
Response.Write( "{ something: """ & something & """ }" )
```

The response.write is returning the correct string { something: "blabla" }
but when I call it with my javascript it reports an error:

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "includes/Process.asp",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            process: "notrelevant",
            formLabel: something
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $(obj).replaceWith(data.casName);
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            alert(a.responseText + "\n" + b + "\n" + c);

            // alerts                 
            //     { something: "blabla" }
            //     parse error
            //     syntax error invalid character
        }
    });
```

Comment: the json output is not valid. Valid Json would be { "something": "blabla" }

Comment: oh for goodness sake lol

Comment: Have you tried your script with the full external url of your process.asp file?

Comment: It's all okay. AarVark71 has answered the question. Needed a "" around the js object name